# In Germany, do insurance payouts get taxed?

Tags: taxes, insurance, germany

I live in Germany and I am a full-time employee.
I subscribed to insurance in a foreign country, on top of the German statutory insurance.

The main benefit of this insurance is that, after 5 years of subscription, I can get 103% of the amount I have paid. As an additional benefit, in case I die because of a disaster, I get paid 1.1x the amount I have paid.

So it is more of a saving plan provided by an insurance company.

Do I have to pay taxes for the payouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you (can) keep it for 12 years and until you are 63, it looks like you can get some tax benefit:

This sounds like the german *"Kapitallebensversicherung"*: you or your next of kind  get the full insurance amount, plus the interest up to that point. It is usually not restricted to dying to a desaster though, so you might want to check that.

A *Kapitallebensversicherung* was (in times with higher interest rates) a reasonable part of the pension system, and as such got similar tax advantages as other pension plans. Old policies (before 2005) were completely tax free - and you were even able to deduct some of your contributions (similar to other pension products).

For a new policy, you would at least pay taxes on only half of your gains - given some requirements though: the policy needs to run for at least 12 years, and should end after you turn 63 (to be reasonably pension-adjacent).

There are some minor additional requirements, and one of those is rather striking: to get the 50%-tax benefit, the payout in case of death after 5 years has to be at least 110% of the principal - which hits your description too precise to have happened at random.

So I assume that the rest of the policy is constructed in a similar way to meet all the requirements. You should double check though, since it might be constructed for the rules of the other country (which just happen to have a similar rule about the 110% because EU harmony or something).

But I think there is a good chance that, provided you keep the policy until you are 63, and for 12 years, you should get the tax benefit.

Otherwise, you will have to pay taxes (*Abgeltungssteuer*, not income taxes) on capital gains. But to clarify: not on the principal (e.g. the money you paid in), just on the 3% gain, as with most other investments.

For completeness: your next of kind might have to pay inheritance tax on the (full) payout, although for most relations, there are high tax exemption limits.